# Debian; Android SDK manager; Android virtual devices

Tags: virtualbox, android, debian, android-sdk

I have debian 7 running on Virtualbox and I have little problem with android virtual devices.

When I open Android Virtual devices and try run one, it successfully begins to open AVD but thats all.

After shapes are created it freezes and screen section is black.

Situation in picture:

[image]

I ran command `egrep -c '(vmx|svm)' /proc/cpuinfo`  to check if cpu supports hardware virtualization**. but it doesn't.

**https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM/Installation#Check_that_your_CPU_supports_hardware_virtualization

So any tips or knowledge is it possible to make it work?

Comment: Please tell us what CPU it is

Comment: Intel(R) Core(TM) i3 CPU    M 370 @ 2.40GHZ

Comment: @Degu are you using Debian or Ubuntu as your host?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go into your BIOS (Usually Delete, F1, or F12 on boot) and Enable VT-x.

This should be a setting somewhere in your BIOS. Depending on the type of computer you have it could be under hardware settings, advanced settings, or something similar. Look around for it.

It might also be called CPU virtualization.

EDIT: See my comment below.
Nested virtualization is not supported by VirtualBox. In other words, you can't run AVD inside a guest OS. The first guest (Ubuntu in this case) will use VT-x on the host, but will not be able to provide VT-x to the nested guest (AVD). The solution here is to dual-boot and run Ubuntu as the host OS.

Comment: In right corner of virtualbox stands.
Addional feature status: VT-x/AMD-V: Enabled  so should be enabled :/

Comment: You're running ubuntu in a virtual machine? That won't work with an AVD inside Ubuntu. Nested virtualization is not supported so the guest OS cannot support VT-x. The setting you're talking about in VirtualBox tells the guest to use those capabilities on the host. You could dual-boot with Ubuntu as the host OS. Then you would have access to VT-x and the AVD would work.

Comment: +1, I didn't notice but yes if you are running in a virtual machine visualization is not accessible, also debian is not ubuntu this is for ubuntu only, ask again here http://forums.debian.net/ as this will probably get closed